# Octave: Vertex color with `patch` command

Tags: matlab, octave

I am using Octave and I am having troubles with the `patch` command. Basically what I want to do is drawing a (black) square without edges but with (red) vertices. I removed the borders by specifying `'EdgeColor','none'` option: e.g.

```
patch([x1,x2,x3,x4],[y1,y2,y3,y4],'red','EdgeColor','none')
```

but I can't seem to find a way to add colored vertices. Anyone knows how?

Comment: Did you try to use the option `marker`together with  `markerFaceColor` and `markerEdgeColor`?

Comment: I tried with the option `'FaceVertexCData'` in `patch` but vertices didn't get colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want markers at the vertices?  You can use the `marker` option (as @H.Muster suggested in a comment), or use `plot` to add the markers separately.

Use the `marker` options of `patch`:

```
octave:69> clf
octave:70> hold on
octave:71> xlim([0 3])
octave:72> ylim([0 3])
octave:73> patch(x, y, 'red', 'EdgeColor', 'none', 'marker', 'o', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'MarkerSize', 30, 'LineStyle', 'none')
```

Or use `plot` to add the markers:

```
octave:48> clf
octave:49> hold on
octave:50> xlim([0 3])
octave:51> ylim([0 3])
octave:52> x = [1 2 2 1];
octave:53> y = [1 1 2 2];
octave:54> patch(x, y, 'red', 'EdgeColor', 'none')
octave:55> plot(x, y, 'o', 'MarkerSize', 12, 'MarkerFaceColor','b')
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks, simple and effective!